# To retrieve specific data from multiple similar portions in a JSON file

Tags: python, json, parsing

A part of JSON file's content as below:

```
{"ID": "PK45", "People": "Kate", "Date": "2020-01-05"}, {"ID": "OI85", "People": "John", "Date": "2020-01-18" }, {"ID": "CN658", "People": "Pevo", "Date": "2020-02-01" }
```

It has multiple portions containing "ID", "People" and "Date".

What I want to do is to retrieve John's ID (in this case "OI85").

If the key is unique, I can use:

```
data_content = json.loads(data)
ID = data_content['ID']
```

But there are multiple similar portions. So I can only locate the "John" first:

```
with open("C:\\the_file.json") as data_file:
    data = data_file.read()
    where = data.find('John')
    where_1 = data[where - 20 : where]
    ID = where_1[where_1.find('ID')+3:where_1.find('ID')+7]
    print (ID)
```

It looked clumsy.

What will be the smart way to retrieve the specific data from multiple similar portions in a JSON file?

Comment: That portion of the json file's content is likely with some unshown outer container like a list. You can iterate through that list and extract the values for each json object (dictionary) within it using the built-in `json` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate on the list of dicts until you find the right one:

```
import json

data = '[{"ID": "PK45", "People": "Kate", "Date": "2020-01-05"}, {"ID": "OI85", "People": "John", "Date": "2020-01-18" }, {"ID": "CN658", "People": "Pevo", "Date": "2020-02-01" }]'

data_content = json.loads(data)

def find_id_by_name(name, data):
    for d in data:
        if d['People'] == name:
            return d["ID"]
    else:
        raise ValueError('Name not found')

print(find_id_by_name('John', data_content))
# OI85

print(find_id_by_name('Jane', data_content))
# ... ValueError: Name not found
```

If you have to do many such searches, it may be worth creating another dict from your data to associate IDs to names:

```
ids_by_name = {d['People']:d['ID'] for d in data_content}
print(ids_by_name['John'])

# OI85
```

Comment: thank you! but it gives "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: `data` is supposed to be the return value of `json.loads(....)`, so what you called in your code `data_content`. I update the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: thank you for the update. Your code work but when I use it on the actual .json file. It gives "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper" from the line "json.loads(...).

Comment: Because `json.loads` is used to load data from a string (hence the final 's'), which is what you also did in the sample code in your question, and you have to use `json.load(<your open file>)` to load data from a file. So, something like `with open('your_filename') as f:  data_content = json.load(f)`

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module, which makes the task trivial:

```python
import json

with open('data.json') as f:
    records = json.load(f)

for record in records:
    if record['People'] == 'John':
        print(record['ID'])
        break
```

Comment: thank you! but it gives "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: The `json` file content is probably not exactly similar to the example you provided then. Please precise it.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up. just the original json file is huge, and I only took portions from it.